# How to find the sum and average of an array using a function and call by reference C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pass-by-reference

We are told to write a function that takes an array of doubles and passes back the sum and average of the numbers in the array

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void sumAverage (double[], int, int &, int &);

int main()
{
double A[10] = { 3.54, 8.12, 39.04, 12.23, 49.32, 90.23};

int sum, average;

sumAverage (A, 10, sum, average);

cout << "The sum is " << A[sum] << endl << endl;
cout << "The average is " << A[average];

return 0;
}

void sumAverage (double array[], int numvalues, int &Asum, int &Aaverage)
{
    double sum = 0;
    
    for (int sub = 0; sub < numvalues; sub++)
        {
            sum += array[sub];
            Asum = sum;
            Aaverage = Asum / numvalues;
        }
        
}
```

I feel like there is something I am missing or not getting about this since I am still fairly new to coding. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: help with what? ... you did not say anything about a problem

Comment: One thought, your array is six deep but you tell `sumAverage` that it is ten items deep. Undefined behavior.

Comment: And why is `sum` an `int`? And why are you referring to `A[sum]`?

Comment: Since your array contains `double`s, why would you want the calculated results of `Asum` and `Aaverage` to be of type `int`?    Using an example with two elements, the sum of `2.1` and `1.2` is `3.3`, the average is `1.65` but computing sum and average as `int` would give `sum` as `3` and average as `1`, which probably is not particularly meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the given code:
1)The input array has only 6 elements, but the function call specifies that there are 10 elements in the array. This can lead to accessing out-of-bounds memory, which is undefined behavior. 2)The function is supposed to pass back the sum and average, but it is actually passing back the index of the sum and average in the array. This is not correct. 3)The calculation of the average is incorrect. It should be Aaverage = sum / numvalues.
Here is a corrected version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void sumAverage(double[], int, double &, double &);

int main()
{
    double A[6] = {3.54, 8.12, 39.04, 12.23, 49.32, 90.23};

    double sum, average;

    sumAverage(A, 6, sum, average);

    cout << "The sum is " << sum << endl;
    cout << "The average is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << average << endl;

    return 0;
}

void sumAverage(double array[], int numvalues, double &Asum, double &Aaverage)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for (int sub = 0; sub < numvalues; sub++)
    {
        sum += array[sub];
    }

    Asum = sum;
    Aaverage = sum / numvalues;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your code mean this.

```cpp
cout << "The sum is " << sum << endl << endl;
cout << "The average is " << average;
```

If you want print decimal point, you need to change the data type of "sum" and "average"

```cpp
double sum,average;
```